# How can I model a Master Page/template with Page Objects, using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I was curious as to the best way to model a page object that could use a master page or template for functions that any page can do in selenium. For example, look at this website. We have questions, tags etc buttons and search box on every page. Every page should be able to search for example. Is the best approach to keep this separated still? So, for example if I wanted to search from the questions page, I would have something like:

```
 @Test
 public void testQuestionWithSearch()
 {
    QuestionPage questionPage = new QuestionPage (driver);
    //do some stuff with question page

    SearchBar search = new SearchBar(driver);
    //search
 }
```

Or could you maybe use inheritance to have some common functionality? For example:

```
public class MasterPage
{
    public SearchPage search(String searchString);
    public TagPage goToTags(WebDriver driver);
}

public class TagPage extends MasterPage {}

@Test 
public void testTagPageWithSearch()
{
     TagPage tagPage = new TagPage (driver);
     tagPage.goToTags(driver);
     tagPage.search("a question");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you are talking about inheritance.

Comment: Yes I am, the question is basically asking if it is better to use inheritance for common functionality like my second example or to still keep all pages separate, even though it may appear on 20 other pages, like a search bar or login link

Comment: This is now getting to be a discussion. :( From personal experience: go with what you know and what you feel comfortable with. If it becomes painful enough down the road, then refactor.

Comment: That's kind of how I felt posting this. I am trying to research the best practices in defining a test automation framework. I thought maybe there would of been a definitive answer. Thanks

Comment: Lots of (Selenium) people like the Page Factory https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory model. If you can wrap your head around it, you're golden!